# Python Error Handling & Connection Errors

Tags: python, bukkit, telnetlib

I'm working on a Telnet client. I started coding on my notebook(Windows) and at the finish I uploaded it on my server(Debian). Both systems works with Python 3. At my notebook the script works well, but on Debian, it does make errors.

The Code:

```
import telnetlib
import sys
try:
    HOST = sys.argv[1]
    user = sys.argv[3]
    password = sys.argv[4]
    cmd= sys.argv[5]
    port=int(sys.argv[2])

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port)

    tn.read_until(b"username: ")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"password: ")
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

    tn.write(cmd.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
except ConnectionRefusedError:
    print('ERROR')
else:
    print('OK')
```

Server(CraftBukkit server with RemoteToolKit):

```
Mar 05, 2014 12:39:58 PM net.wimpi.telnetd.net.ConnectionManager makeConnection
INFO: connection #1 made.
Unexpected error in shell!
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:118)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:159)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140)
>       at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:123)
>       at net.wimpi.telnetd.io.TelnetIO.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at net.wimpi.telnetd.io.TerminalIO.flush(Unknown Source)
>       at net.wimpi.telnetd.io.TerminalIO.write(Unknown Source)
>       at com.drdanick.McRKit.Telnet.ConsoleShell.run(ConsoleShell.java:78)
>       at net.wimpi.telnetd.net.Connection.run(Unknown Source)
Mar 05, 2014 12:39:58 PM net.wimpi.telnetd.net.ConnectionManager cleanupClosed
INFO: cleanupClosed():: Removing closed connection Thread[Connection1,5,]
```

Greets miny

EDIT: The error handling works now! THX @ Wojciech Walczak
The client doesn't report errors, but the server reports errors. If I run the same code on Windows, it doesn't make errors.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you're running the script in `python3` on Debian?

Comment: Yes, I use the cmd python3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the script. The telnet command on Linux works well.

Comment: Could you run your code without the try/except clauses and post full traceback?

Comment: No errors, I think the problem are the byte strings

Answer (score 1):

...and are you sure you're using Python 3.3 or later? `ConnectionRefusedError` has been added in Python 3.3.

EDIT:

Given that your client works fine when launched from your laptop, and is catching `ConnectionRefusedError` on another machine, I would say that the problem is not the script itself. It's rather about server's telnet/firewall settings. Are other telnet clients working in the environment in which your script is failing?

Comment: I updated now Python to 3.3.4. One problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

The reason for the traceback when the server is offline is because you are trying to trap a non-existent exception (which is to say that the name `ConnectionRefusedError` has not yet been assigned a value).

Solely for its educational purpose I would remove the `try ... except ..." and let the error be raised Then hopefully you will find out exactly what exception is being raised.

As to the Java traceback, WTF?

Answer (score 0):

I ran the code w/o try and except and it doesn't report errors.

I made some tests with byte strings.

If I run this code, the machines displays different strings.

Command:

```
print(b"Hello there!")
```

Windows:

```
b"Hello there!"
```

Linux:

```
Hello there!
```

Comment: I presume that there's still an error on the server side? If so, what happens when you drop the `b`'s in your telnet client? (Please, answer below my comment.)

Comment: There's no error at server-side. I tested the server with PuTTY. `tn.write(b'say Hi')` That works `tn.write("say Hi".encode('ascii'))` That doesn't work

Comment: Is there any problem, then?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "UDPClient.py", line 12, in <module>
    tn.read_until("username: ")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 299, in read_until
    return self._read_until_with_select(match, timeout)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\telnetlib.py", line 352, in _read_until_with_select
    i = self.cookedq.find(match)
TypeError: Type str doesn't support the buffer API

Comment: The traceback suggests that the problem is in `tn.read_until()` function, and not in the `tn.write()` function. Could you update your original message with your current code and current errors? In general, the error you're seeing now is a matter of mixing bytes and strings. Try: `b'str1, str2'.find('str')` and `b'str1, str2'.find(b'str')`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated Code at Debian (Windows uses still the old code):

```
import telnetlib
import sys
if(True):
    HOST = sys.argv[1]
    user = sys.argv[3]
    password = sys.argv[4]
    cmd= sys.argv[5]
    port=int(sys.argv[2])

    tn = telnetlib.Telnet(HOST, port)

    tn.read_until(b"username:")
    tn.write(user.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
    if password:
        tn.read_until(b"password:")
        tn.write(password.encode('ascii') + b"\n")

    tn.write(cmd.encode('ascii') + b"\n")
```

I tested the code at Windows and the telnet server can run the commands.
When I run the code at Debian, it doesn't say nothing, but the server says *Connection reset".